# Why negative energy particles not created near a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime, pair-production

If you take empty space right next to a black hole once in awhile, you will get a positive particle being admitted in the opposite direction of the black hole. In the creation of the photon this demands that a negative energy is supplied in the opposite direction of the positive particle which would be into the black hole. But why can this not happen the other way around?

Comment: The picture of "virtual particles becoming real at the horizon" is but a sketch, only useful for the layman, and is *not* what is happening, if anything happens at all. In fact, it is meaningless to trace back the radiations up to the horizon.

Comment: What happens then and/or can you direct me to a source that will tell me what was actually happening

Comment: [Hawking's original paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02345020) is a good start (although he is the one who gave the virtual particles explanation, he says right after that this is not to be trusted). Shortly, Hawking radiation is an instance of the relativity of the concept of energy.

Comment: Your description is incorrect - there is no such thing as negative energy. When a pair of particles is created, both have a positive energy. Their total combined energy comes from the energy of the black hole. When one of the particles flies away, the energy of the black hole drops by the amount of energy of this particle, whichever particle it is. Your question is based on a wrong premise.